# Node.js application running in the background with pkg

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, hidden

I need to build an application via the `pkg` package, which in turn will run directly in the background.

I tried `child_process`, but it didn't help me. It runs scripts in the background outside of the built `pkg` application, but the application itself should be a single built application with all dependencies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.